# How would i go on scraping only online telegram members from a group?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

So i found this piece of code somewhere on stackoverflow:

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty, InputPeerChannel, InputPeerUser
from telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist import PeerFloodError, UserPrivacyRestrictedError
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import InviteToChannelRequest
import sys
import csv
import traceback
import time
from datetime import datetime
api_id =  123456789 #Enter Your 7 Digit Telegram API ID.
api_hash = '123456789'   #Enter Yor 32 Character API Hash.
phone = '123456789'
client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)

client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code recieved to your Telegram messenger: '))


chats = []
last_date = None
chunk_size = 200
groups=[]

result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
             offset_date=last_date,
             offset_id=0,
             offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
             limit=chunk_size,
             hash = 0
         ))
chats.extend(result.chats)

for chat in chats:
    try:
        if chat.megagroup== True:
            groups.append(chat)
    except:
        continue

print('Choose a group to scrape members from:')
i=0
for g in groups:
    print(str(i) + '- ' + g.title)
    i+=1

g_index = input("Enter a Number: ")
target_group=groups[int(g_index)]

print('Fetching Members...')
all_participants = []
all_participants = client.get_participants(target_group, aggressive=True)

print('Saving In file...')
with open("Scraped.csv","w",encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
    writer.writerow(['username','user id', 'access hash','name','group', 'group id','last seen'])
    for user in all_participants:
        accept=True
        try:
            lastDate=user.status.was_online
            num_months = (datetime.now().year - lastDate.year) * 12 + (datetime.now().month - lastDate.month)
            if(num_months>1):
                accept=False
        except:
            continue

        if (accept) :
            if user.username:
                username= user.username
            else:
                username= ""
            if user.first_name:
                first_name= user.first_name
            else:
                first_name= ""
            if user.last_name:
                last_name= user.last_name
            else:
                last_name= ""
            name= (first_name + ' ' + last_name).strip()
            writer.writerow([username,user.id,user.access_hash,name,target_group.title, target_group.id,user.status]) 

print('Members scraped successfully.')
```

And this pretty much scrapes online & recently active members, how would i change this to ONLY scrape online members? I tried looking into the telethon docs but i don't seem to understand...
I'm not sure where else to ask for help regarding this issue so here i am...

Any sort of help is highly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Scraping ONLY online members is not possible.

Try something like this:

```
import telethon
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetParticipantsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputChannel
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsSearch
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetFullChannelRequest

api_id = 123567
api_hash = "dsaopdas2131"
client = TelegramClient("RDJR", api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage())
async def handler(event):
    chat_id = event.message.peer_id.channel_id
    offset = 0
    limit = 200
    my_filter = ChannelParticipantsSearch('')
    channel = await client(GetFullChannelRequest(chat_id))
    participants = await client(GetParticipantsRequest(channel=chat_id, filter=my_filter, offset=offset, limit=limit, hash=0))
    for x in participants.users:
        print(x.status)

with client as client:
    print("USER_BOT ONLINE!")
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

You need to get all of the participants of a group/channel, then iterate them to print the status.

The output would be something like this:
User online:

```
UserStatusOnline(expires=datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 6, 21, 6, 22, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc))
```

Or:

```
None
```

User offline:

```
UserStatusOffline(was_online=datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 6, 18, 19, 35, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc))
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for this. I found a different method although i still need help.